# Custom user_register_form for Auto Assign Role registration pages

Tags: forms, users, theming

I'm using a function[a] to get custom templates to work for all pages, including role registration pages set by [Auto Assign Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/autoassignrole). By setting the role registration path to `user/register/<rolename>` I'm able to use `page--user--register--rolename.tpl.php` to make custom pages.

[image]

What I'm trying to do now is use a custom user_register_form for each role registration page. Using this function[b] I'm able to use `user-register-form.tpl.php` to customize the registration form. This affects the form for both role pages though. I tried using the Field Permissions module, but because an anonymous user will be using both forms it's of no use here.

I'm thinking I need to change what user-register-form template the page itself is looking for, but I can't figure out how to do that.

a.

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

  if (isset($vars['node'])) {

    $suggests = &$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'];

    $args = arg();
    // Remove first argument of "node".
    unset($args[0]);

    $type = "page__type_{$vars['node']->type}";

    $suggests = array_merge(
      $suggests,
      array($type),
      theme_get_suggestions($args, $type)
    );
  }
}
```

b.

```
 function THEMENAME_theme() {
  $items = array();

  $items['user_login'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEMENAME') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'user-login',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
       'THEMENAME_preprocess_user_login'
    ),
  );
  $items['user_register_form'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEMENAME') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'user-register-form',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
      'THEMENAME_preprocess_user_register_form'
    ),
  );
  $items['user_pass'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEMENAME') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'user-pass',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
      'THEMENAME_preprocess_user_pass'
    ),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you already have a template file for the form user-register-form.tpl.php, you should be able to use a preprocess like this:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_user_register_form($vars) {
  // if role2
  // use other theme
}
```

There should be no need to define your own themes with hook_theme

Comment: I'm new to drupal theming (I copied those functions from elsewhere). Where would I go to learn how to build what you're describing from scratch? I can't tell if the hook_preprocess_HOOK(), hook_theme() or theme() doc page is where I should start. I think it's the first one, but I'm having trouble relating what I see on the user_register_form() page to what I'm seeing described there.

Comment: maybe start with the [drupal theming docs](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/theme)

Comment: I looked through them but couldn't figure this out. I think the problem is this being a third party module. I need to either affect the user_register_form template being used by the path or in the module itself. AFAIK `if role` checks for the user's role, not the role being auto assigned. This being a registration page the role will always be anonymous.